# How to parse a path in Neo4j Go driver

Tags: go, neo4j

I am trying to use Neo4j Go Driver.

I have written this code snippet to get the path from node 1 to node 5, However not able to properly get the results mentioned in the api.

```
result, err = session.Run("match (n:Xyz{title:1}),(m:Xyz{title:5}),p=allShortestPaths((n)-[*]->(m)) return p",nil)

    if err != nil {
        return "",err
    }


    for result.Next() {
        keys := result.Record().Keys()
        fmt.Println(keys)
        values_NEO := result.Record().Values()
        nodes := values_NEO[0].Nodes()
        labels := nodes.Labels()
        fmt.Println(labels)
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
values_NEO[0].Nodes undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

My Graph is this:
[image: Graph]

Any suggestion would be a huge help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I assume you're using this driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j).

`result.Record().Values()` returns `[]interface{}`.

So the type of `values_NEO[0]` is `interface{}`, which does not have a method called `Nodes()`. A type that *does* have that method is `Path`.

I'm not familiar with neo4j but if you're expecting `values_NEO[0]` to be of type `Path`, you'll have to type assert, like this: `values_NEO[0].(neo4j.Path).Nodes()`.

Comment: I tried to find the api spec for Values in this driver, did not got it, can you please share the link, and is there a clean way to write this in loop way ?

Comment: `Values()` is a method of [Record](https://godoc.org/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j#Record). You just need to replace `values_NEO[0].Nodes()` with `values_NEO[0].(neo4j.Path).Nodes()` in your program.

Comment: Sure this works, I tried this. However was hoping if there is some way to make it more cleaner or I will have to always access nodes in such way :-/

Comment: You can type-assert and save the asserted value, e.g. `path := values_NEO[0].(neo4j.Path)` and do something with `path` later. For example, save it into a `[]neo4j.Path` slice or pass it as an argument to a function expecting a `neo4j.Path`.